# Change multiple things in header using sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have the following dataset.

> ```
> CHROM   POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   {ALLELE:FREQ}
> 6       85401233        2       46      T:1     A:0
> 6       85401234        2       46      C:1     G:0
> 6       85401235        2       46      T:1     G:0
> ```

I want to change the header of 5th column, then split to 2 columns.

> ```
> REF     ALT
> T:1     A:0
> C:1     G:0
> T:1     G:0
> ```

I can convert ':' to tab delimiter by using sed. It works

```
sed '1s/\:/\t/g' filename
```

But these commands do not work as I want.

```
sed '1s/\{ALLELE:/ALT\t/g' filename
```

It gives this message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

and

```
sed '1s/\:/\t/g' | '1s/\{ALLELE/REF /g' filename

-bash: 1s/\{ALLELE/REF /g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems they were already split as two columns. only header is required to be edited. Can u confirm?

Comment: Yes only header is required to be edited. Thanks also for editing in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the file contents, all you want is `ed`, the standard editor:

```
$ cat filename
CHROM   POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   {ALLELE:FREQ}
6       85401233        2       46      T:1     A:0
6       85401234        2       46      C:1     G:0
6       85401235        2       46      T:1     G:0
$ printf '%b\n' '1s/{ALLELE:FREQ}/REF\011ALT/' 'w' 'q'|ed -s filename
$ cat filename
CHROM   POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   REF     ALT
6       85401233        2       46      T:1     A:0
6       85401234        2       46      C:1     G:0
6       85401235        2       46      T:1     G:0
```

- `'1s/{ALLELE:FREQ}/REF\011ALT/'` goes to line 1 and makes the substitution. `\011` is the octal for the tab character, converted into a tab by `printf`.
- `'w' 'q'` saves the modifications to the file and quits the editor.

---

```
sed '1s/\{ALLELE:/ALT\t/g' filename
```

fails because `\{` is special in basic regular expressions. You meant simply `{`.

And here

```
sed '1s/\:/\t/g' | '1s/\{ALLELE/REF /g' filename
```

you did not provide the input file to the first sed, so it fails. The correct, straightforward sed command would be

```
sed '1s/{ALLELE:FREQ}/REF\tALT/' filename
```

Notice you do not need the `g` flag either: There is just one match to be replaced in the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I really appreciated it!